# Do anonymous block boxes behave differently than "normal" block boxes?

Tags: html, css

```css
span {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<span>
  A
  <div>
    B
  </div>
  C
</span>
```

[Block-level boxes inside inline boxes (div child of span)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74830651/block-level-boxes-inside-inline-boxes-div-child-of-span)

I understand that A and C are *anonymous block boxes*, so, why don't they center the text?

**The post ALREADY has an answer**, but I still don't understand the answer, **I would like more details**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#formal_definition

The text-align documentation says that it applies to **block containers**, so I think it should be centered the text, or do anonymous block boxes **behave differently than "normal" block boxes**?

This is confusing because the `div` that is a block box container does inherit the text-align property

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level

> The properties of anonymous boxes **are inherited from the enclosing
> non-anonymous box** (e.g., in the example just below the subsection
> heading "Anonymous block boxes", the one for DIV). Non-inherited
> properties have their initial value. For example, the font of the
> anonymous box is inherited from the DIV, but the margins will be 0.

Comment: `<span>` is an **inline** element, not a block element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

Comment: divs cannot be children of spans

Comment: hi @ĐinhCarabu but, what are you getting at with that statement?

Comment: hi @j08691, thank you, I know, but I need to know why this happened, in case there is an explanation

Comment: @yt55 you seem to think that `<span>` behaves like regular **block** elements e.g. `<div>` which it does not. Inline Elements only take up as much space horizontally as needed. So unless you add `display: block;` to your css it won't work. But nesting a `<div>` inside a `<span>` doesn't make that much sense in the first place. Why can't you just use another `<div>`?

Comment: *"Why can't you just use another `<div>`?"* - Yes I can, I just wanted to understand why this happens according to the specifications @Đinh Carabus

Comment: Why the -1 if the question is **NOT EQUAL**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this we need to take into account the block container that contains the span. Let's assume that's the body element. This is what the box tree looks like:

[image: DOM Document to Box Tree mapping]

Now the point is that the span element is broken around the div element. So the anonymous block boxes are constructed from the sections of the DOM document (depicted in orange above) consisting of the first part of the span **+** the "A" text, and the last part of the span **+** the "C" text.

> Do anonymous block boxes behave differently than "normal" block boxes?

Yes. Anonymous block boxes inherit directly through the box tree hierarchy. Normal (a.k.a "named" or "non-anonymous") block boxes inherit through the DOM document hierarchy.

This means that the anonymous block boxes inherit from the body element, not from the span. In contrast, the named block box created by the div inherits from the span.

Comment: hi @Alohci, thanks excellent information, now I have several questions. - "*So the anonymous block boxes are constructed from the sections of the DOM document*" - What do you mean by "sections of the DOM document"?

Comment: @yt55 - What I said. e.g. The first section is the first part of the span + the "A" text. The anonymous block box is the container of that section.

Comment: That means that the "*...are inherited from the enclosing non-anonymous box...*" rule applies as long as the enclosing non-anonymous box **is block-level** (i.e., the nearest block-level element). Or, what do you mean by this "*This means that the anonymous block boxes inherit from the body element, not from the span.*"? @Alohci

Comment: @yt55 - 1. In the context of the paragraph in the CSS 2.2 spec, the enclosing non-anonymous box is a block box. Block boxes are, by definition block-level. In general, however that doesn't have to be the case. Where I've said in the answer, "let's assume that the block container is the body element", any block container would do, even one that isn't block-level, such as a table cell.  2. For what I mean, look at the box tree in the diagram. The parent of the anonymous block boxes is the block container box created by the body element so that's what they inherit from.

Comment: The `span` was split into 2 anonymous block boxes and into the `div` itself because of what this rule says, "*When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) is broken around the block-level box...*", right? @Alohci

Comment: @yt55 - that's right.

Comment: Hi @Alohci excellent answer +1. The rule of breaking an inline box around a block-level element is to "eliminate the possibility" of an inline element containing block-level elements, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - I don't think so. This is not dogma - "Thou shalt not have an inline element containing block-level elements", it's pragmatism - "There's an (nest of) inline element(s) containing a block-level element, how can this be sanely laid out?"

Comment: @yt55 - I don't understand what you're asking there. Inline layout doesn't generate block boxes. The generating of the block box - anonymous or named - happens external to the inline layout.

Comment: What I mean is that  an anonymous block box has a root inline box from which "everything starts" (from there that root inline box will have descendants), right? @Alohci

Comment: @yt55. Yes, that's correct.